# how to group data according to UserID?

Tags: c#, linq

Everyone!
I am new to MVC and Linq and I have some problems with these code.
I want to group organizationId according to UserId but it only shows an organizationId per UserId in my View.
Actually, I want to get all organizationId with the same UserId.
How can i get it?

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var datas = _userInOrganizationService.UserInOrganizations.GetByAll().ToList();
    var userdata = ApplicationUserManager.Users.Where(x => x.Active == true).ToList();
    var orgdata = _userInOrganizationService.Organizations
        .GetByAll().ToList();            

    List<UserInOrganizationViewModel> data = (
      from z in datas
      join user in userdata on z.UserID equals user.Id
      join org in orgdata on z.OrganizationID equals org.OrganizationID
      select new UserInOrganizationViewModel
    {

      UserID = user.Id,
      UserName = user.UserName,
      FullName = user.FullName,
      Email = user.Email,

      NRCNo = user.NRCNo,
          Organizations = ShowOrganizaton(org.OrganizationID),

          PasswordQuestion = user.PasswordQuestion,
      PasswordAnswer = user.PasswordAnswer,
      CreatedDate = user.CreatedDate,
      UpdatedDate = user.UpdatedDate
    }).Distinct().ToList();

    return View(data);
}

public List<Organization> ShowOrganizaton(string orgid)
{
    var data = _userInOrganizationService.Organizations.GetByAll().Where(x => x.Active == true && x.OrganizationID == orgid).AsEnumerable().ToList();

    return data;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add `.GroupBy(u => u.UserID)` to your LINQ statement.

This will order all records by UserID

Comment: where can i put it, Sir? In which line?

Comment: You could use it like `_userInOrganizationService.Organizations.GetByAll().Where(x => x.Active == true && x.OrganizationID == orgid).GroupBy(u => u.UserID).AsEnumerable().ToList();`